# Javascript tooltip functionality for inserted text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

I have been using this [simple tooltip library](http://www.alessioatzeni.com/blog/simple-tooltip-with-jquery-only-text/), consisting of around ten lines of jQuery. The examples work fine, as shown in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c7dw8e28/).

The problem is occurring when I try to insert new text that I still want the tooltip to activate for.

```
 <input type="button" value="add text" id="add" />

  $("#add").click(function(){
      $('body').append("<p title=\"Mouse over the heading above to view the tooltip.\" class=\"masterTooltip\">Mouse over the heading text above to view it's tooltip.</p>")
  });
```

The text by itself activates the tooltip, but when appended after the body loads, there is no functionality. I've tried this for several tags but all with the same result. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$('.masterTooltip').hover(...).mousemove(...)` attaches event handlers only to elements that exist at that time.

You could apply that same `.hover().mousemove()` code within your `click` handler, but I think it is easier to instead use [the delegated syntax for the `.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) to attached delegated event handlers to the `document`, passing the `'.masterTooltip'` selector as an argument such that when the event occurs jQuery will automatically test whether the event applied to an element matching that selector. The basic syntax would be:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.masterTooltip', function() { ... })
```

...but given you want three event handlers, `mouseenter`, `mouseleave`, and `mousemove` to apply to the same elements you can [pass an object to `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data) as follows:

```
  $(document).on({
    'mouseenter': function() {
      // Hover over code
      var title = $(this).attr('title');
      $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
      $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
        .text(title)
        .appendTo('body')
        .fadeIn('slow');
    },
    'mouseleave': function() {
      // Hover out code
      $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
      $('.tooltip').remove();
    },
    'mousemove': function(e) {
      var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
      var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
      $('.tooltip')
        .css({
          top: mousey,
          left: mousex
        })
    }
  }, '.masterTooltip');   // NOTE the selector on this line
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c7dw8e28/1/

EDIT, P.S. Note that the `.hover()` method you used originally is a convenience method to add `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` handlers, but when using `.on()` you have to explicitly define `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, as I have shown.